# Difficulty setting window dimension in constructor tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to have the window initialize at a set dimension such as 600x500. I am having difficulty doing this through the constructor in the GUI_window class.

I have tried entering the arguments width = 600 height = 500 into

```
tk.Tk.__init__(HERE)
```

but it results in the error: "**init**() got an unexpected key word argument 'width'."
I have also tried writing it in the initial calling parameter as such

```
GUI_window(width = 600, height = 500)
```

but i am greeted with the same error message

tkinter is imported as such:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Here is the class in which the error occurs, (line 2 of this block)

```
class GUI_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        self.frames = {}
```

I call the method with these lines at the end of the programme.

```
GUI = GUI_window()
GUI.mainloop()
```

I expect the window size to fit the values that I enter but instead i get the aforementioned error messages. How can I set the window to a specific size in this object format without getting this error?

Comment: `GUI.geometry("600x500")`

Comment: you can also set position (100, 200) with `geometry("600x500+100+200")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set window size you have to use

```
 GUI.geometry("600x500")
```

Or inside constructor

```
self.geometry("600x500")
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("600x500")

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

GUI = GUI_window()
GUI.mainloop()
```

---

You could send it in constructor

```
GUI_window(width=600, height=500)
```

but later you would have to remove `width` and `height` from `**kwargs` before you use `**kwargs` in `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

---

**EDIT:** version which uses `width=600, height=500` and it has no problem with `kwargs`. It needs default values in `__init__` if you want to use `GUI_window()` without `width=600, height=500`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, width=300, height=300, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

GUI = GUI_window(width=600, height=500)
#GUI = GUI_window()
GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added new example in answer.